# SQLite функция TIME - TIME('2335556', 'unixepoch') возвращает как 00:45:56

Tags: windows, sqlite

Да вот собственно в заголовке и весь вопрос: 
вызов TIME('2335556', 'unixepoch') возвращает результат 00:45:56

Максимальное правильное значение возвращает при количестве секунд до 86399 - результат 23:59:59

Кто подскажет, как с этим побороться?

Уточню вопрос - как получить количество дней, часов, минут и секунд (а лучше часов-минут-секунд)?

Comment: А там нет функций DATE или DATETIME?

Comment: Ну правильно же возвращает, зачем с этим бороться?

Comment: Alexander Prokoshev: Правильно? с 3 по 30 августа (2335556 сек)  - 45 мин и 56 сек?

Comment: Qwertiy: Есть DATE - плюс-минус какое-то время - не то. Есть DATETIME - дя, для данного кол-ва секунд возвращает 1970-01-28 03:45:56 , а мне бы нужно кол-во часов-минут-секунд...

Comment: Правильно. 2335556 секунд с начала эпохи — это без пятнадцати час ночи 28-го дня эпохи. Но функция TIME по определению не включает в себя DATE и не считает интервалы - она даёт время суток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно получить интервал в сутках-часах-минутах-секундах, то возьмите результат от целочисленного деления количества секунд на 86400, потом результат целочисленного деления остатка от предыдущей операции на 3600, потом результат целочисленного деления остатка от предыдущей операции на 60, потом остаток от последней операции — и вот у вас дни, часы, минуты и секунды соответственно!

Если дни не нужны, то начинайте с целочисленного деления количества секунд на 3600.

Comment: Да, спасибо, но один вопрос: даже не спрашиваю как, надеюсь что-то напишу :) , а вот в запросе это реально сделать? Или писать последующую обработку? Я не очень силен в запросах, потому и такой вот вопрос...

Comment: @IAfonin Не знаю. Не исключаю. Но вы же всё равно к SQLite ходите из какой-то, видимо, своей программы а не просто с командной строки, так что поделить не должно составить особого труда. В принципе, оно и SQLite как такового не подразумевает, т.к. может вы и не оттуда секунды берёте.